# Makefile conditional statements not working

Tags: c, netbeans, makefile

I have the following makefile code where the `ifeq` statement is not evaluating to true and I don't understand why not:

```
PROCESSOR=`uname -p`

ifeq ($(strip $(PROCESSOR)), x86_64)
PROCESSOR = -c -march=atom -fPIC -Wall -I../../inc
else
PROCESSOR = -c -march=i386 -fPIC -Wall -I../../inc
endif
```

I have confirmed on my system that `uname -p` results in "x86_64", but the `ifeq` statement is evaluating to false and `PROCESSOR` is being set to `-c -march=i386 -fPIC -Wall -I../../inc`.  I have also tried `ifeq "$(strip $(PROCESSOR))" "x86_64"` and a few variations without the `strip` function.  Anyone have any suggestions?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Backticks aren't command execution in a makefile.

Add `$(info $(PROCESSOR))` above the `ifeq` line to see what I mean.

You want:

```
PROCESSOR=$(shell uname -p)

$ cat Makefile
PROCESSOR=`uname -p`
$(info backticks: $(PROCESSOR))
PROCESSOR=$(shell uname -p)
$(info $$shell: $(PROCESSOR))
$ make
backticks: `uname -p`
$shell: x86_64
```

Comment: thank you so much!. the $(shell   command is exactly what I needed and I got my makefile to work properly